# как сделать такую штуку на чистом css, если конечно возможно

Tags: html, css

нужно ли для такой стрелки создавать новый тег ?
как сверстать его, самим  блоком я справлюсь, но вот как разумно будет сделать стрелку такую

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: смотрите тут: http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/

Comment: да да !! спасибо, что поправили

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы конечно нарисовал на `svg`, но вот `html` + `css`, раз так сильно хочется:

```css
div.example {
  position: absolute;
  height: 75px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: 150ms;
}

div.example:hover {
  height: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.example:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -15px;
  content: '';
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
  border-top: 15px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="example"><div>
```

Вот только `svg` вариант:

```css
path {
  transition:100ms;
  fill:red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

path:hover{
  transform: translate(0, 25px);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 150" width="50" height="150">
  <path d='
    M0,-50 
    l50,0
    l0,125
    l-25,15
    l-25,-15
    z
  '></path>
</svg>
```

На первый взгляд разницы нет, но как только Вы начнете пытаться сделать например градиентный фон для этой фигуры или еще какой нибудь тройной бордер Вы увидите что `svg` вариант намного более гибок чем `css` вариант.

```css
path:hover{
  transform: translate(0, 25px);
}

path {
  fill: red;
  fill-opacity: 0;
  stroke-width: 2.2px;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-miterlimit: 5;
  stroke-dashArray: 1111;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1111;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-name: fill-stroke,  fill-body;
  animation-duration: 2.5s, 1s;
  animation-delay: 0s,  1s;
  transition: 100ms;
  cursor: pointer;
}

path:hover{
  transform: translate(0, 25px);
}
    
@keyframes fill-stroke {
  to {
    stroke-dashOffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes fill-body {
  from {
    fill-opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    fill-opacity: 0.5;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-5 -5 60 150" width="50" height="150">
  <path d='M0,-50 l50,0 l0,125 l-25,15 l-25,-15 z'></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Чувак, я не знаю как тебя отблагодарить :)) ну этот вариант намного круче

Comment: @John если угодно - почитайте опусы по ссылкам из моего профиля, может что-то полезное для себя найдете =)